# how to add unique values to DB table using SQL, so that there will be now duplicate rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is the query I am trying:

```
INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Description, Brand, Size, Variety, Manufacturer, Family, Category, SubCategory ) 
VALUES ('m', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Product.ProductName = 'm')`
```

and this the exception I am getting:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Query input must contain at least one table or query.

Comment: For which RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constraint for the field ProductName in the table. This way the DBMS will not allow you to insert an entry with an existing ProductName.

Also it's recommended to have a special Primary Key field (ProductId for example) populated using a sequence. It's better when you need a reference to the product from either other table or some place beyond the DB.

P.S.: using a query that check if a row with specified ProductName doesn't exist and then inserting a new row doesn't actually saves you from duplicate products in the table. Two such queries being executed simultaneously in separate transactions both will be able to successfully insert a row into the table. As a result you'll have a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful, i made the ProductName field unique and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax, not `INSERT ... VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO Product 
( ProductName, Description, Brand, Size, Variety, Manufacturer, 
  Family, Category, SubCategory 
) 
SELECT
    'm','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m'
FROM dual 
WHERE not exists 
      (select * from Product where Product.ProductName='m')
```

If it is for MS-Access, then you don't have a `dual` table available. You can either create a dummy `dual` table - with just one row - and use it afterwards or use this:

```
INSERT INTO Product 
( ProductName, Description, Brand, Size, Variety, Manufacturer, 
  Family, Category, SubCategory 
) 
SELECT
    'm','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m'
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM a_table_with_at_least_one row) AS dummy
WHERE not exists 
      (select * from Product where Product.ProductName='m')
```

---

If, however, you want to never have 2 rows with same `Product.ProductName`, then you could just declare the `Product.ProductName` column as `UNIQUE` and use the `INSERT ... VALUES` syntax - without the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` part, just fine:

```
INSERT INTO Product 
( ProductName, Description, Brand, Size, Variety, Manufacturer, 
  Family, Category, SubCategory 
) 
VALUES
    ('m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m')
```

An error will be thrown whenever you try to add a second row with the same product name as an existing one.

Comment: DUAL only exists if this is an Oracle DMBS.

Comment: @N West: Correct. In MySQL, too.

Comment: @Al Ammar: you'd better use the second piece of advise here - unlike constraint usage of such query won't actually protect you from duplicates in the table.

Comment: As @Andrei pointes, adding a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) constraint on product.name is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't appear to be well formed. INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (values) typically doesn't allow a where clause.

The documentation for MS Access SQL is here (since it appears you are using Access ODBC?) I don't see anything to indicate you can use this logic as you're trying to do.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/insert-into-statement-HP001032245.aspx

What you will need to do instead is query the table with your java application first to determine if a record exists with a product name of 'm', and if it does, don't fire the "insert". You could also add a constraint to the column if your dbms allows it.